# LINQ Lazy load or query incorrect

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

LINQ Query not populating

Model extract is as follows

```
public class ServiceBulletin 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<ServiceBulletinProducts> ApplicableProducts { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class ServiceBulletinProducts
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ServiceBulletinId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the following code at the moment to populate a collection

```
var x = from m in _dc.ServiceBulletins.Include(p => p.ApplicableProducts)
                                              .Include(m => m.Manufacturer)                    
                where m.DeleteStatus == DeleteStatus.Active                          
                select m;

        var x1 = new List<ServiceBulletin>();

        foreach (var item in x)
        {
            var p = from m1 in _dc.ServiceBulletinsProducts.Include(p2=>p2.Product)                                                   
                         where m1.Product.DeleteStatus == DeleteStatus.Active &&
                         m1.ServiceBulletinId == item.Id
                         select m1;

            var p99 = p.ToList();
           item.ApplicableProducts = p99;
            x1.Add(item);
        };
```

So this is intended to have a Parent Child relationship and I’m trying to do a query which populates a collection of ServiceBulletins with a ApplicableProducts item with a fully populated collection of ServiceBulletinProducts for the ServiceBulletin with the values of the Product populated

The collection is populated but the ServiceBulletinProducts are always set to null and I can’t seem to add an Include such as .Include(p => p.ApplicableProducts.Products) to try and populate the product details – which is resulting in me iterating around the collection to populate the items.

Am I missing something to enable the population on the 1st query for the Include statement or do I need to do the query in a different way ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the following should do the trick.

```
      var x = from m in _dc.ServiceBulletins.Include(p => p.ApplicableProducts.Select(p2=>p2.Product))
                                                    .Include(m => m.Manufacturer)
                where m.DeleteStatus == DeleteStatus.Active
                select m;
```